# T-SQL insert to shopping cart, goes in the worong else - UPDATED

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

Hi i don't know how to solve this problem

**UPDATE
write new sql but same error.
I know the error, when debugging.
In every if and else it does this:**

```
    SET @ShoppingCartId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    INSERT INTO ShoppingCartItems(ShoppingCartId,ProductID, Quantity)
    VALUES(@ShoppingCartId, @ProductID, @Quantity)
```

**That is only to happen if the shoppingcart dont exists.**

**If there is a way to break out of the code after it's done would solve it.**

ShoppingCart

[image: ShoppingCart]

ShoppingCartItems

[image: ShoppingCartItems]

Stored Procedure

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT ShoppingCart.ShoppingCartId FROM ShoppingCart WHERE 

ShoppingCart.ShoppingCartId = @ShoppingCartId)
--if shoppingcart exists
--check if product exists
IF EXISTS(SELECT ShoppingCartItems.Id FROM ShoppingCartItems WHERE ShoppingCartItems.ProductID = @ProductID AND ShoppingCartItems.ShoppingCartId = @ShoppingCartId)
--Om produkten existerar
BEGIN
UPDATE ShoppingCartItems
SET Quantity = Quantity + 1
WHERE ProductID = @ProductID AND ShoppingCartItems.ShoppingCartId = @ShoppingCartId
END
ELSE
--of product dont exists
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ShoppingCartItems(ShoppingCartId,ProductID, Quantity)
    VALUES(@ShoppingCartId, @ProductID, @Quantity)
    END
ELSE
--if shoppingcart dont exists
--Insert new shoppingcart
    INSERT INTO ShoppingCart(UserID, DateAdded)
    VALUES(@UserID, GETDATE())
    SET @ShoppingCartId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    INSERT INTO ShoppingCartItems(ShoppingCartId,ProductID, Quantity)
    VALUES(@ShoppingCartId, @ProductID, @Quantity)
```

The results i get is:

First execution

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[AddShoppingCart]
        @ProductID = 1,
        @Quantity = 1,
        @UserID = NULL,
        @ShoppingCartId = NULL
```

And Second Execution

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[AddShoppingCart]
    @ProductID = 1,
    @Quantity = 1,
    @UserID = NULL,
    @ShoppingCartId = 1
```

Everyting looks fine here

[image]
[image]

But i get a error message.

**(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure AddShoppingCart, Line 26
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ShoppingCartId', table 'MustTest.dbo.ShoppingCartItems'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.**

After 3rd test when i try to insert the second product in the same shoppingcart

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[AddShoppingCart]
    @ProductID = 2,
    @Quantity = 1,
    @UserID = NULL,
    @ShoppingCartId = 1
```

My result is all wrong, it inserts product 2 two times and the second time with a ShoppingCartId i didn't put in.

[image]

Comment: Did you make your primary key as Identity column? So it can autoincrement by itself.

Comment: As you can see in the second execution i provided @ShoppingCartId = 1

Yes both primary keys is identity

Comment: I updated my code, i know my error but not how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I think it's now working

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddShoppingCart]
    @ProductID int,
    @Quantity int,
    @UserID nvarchar(128),
    @ShoppingCartId int
AS
IF EXISTS(SELECT ShoppingCart.ShoppingCartId FROM ShoppingCart WHERE ShoppingCart.ShoppingCartId = @ShoppingCartId)
    --Om kundvagnen existerar
    --Kolla om produkten existerar
    IF EXISTS(SELECT ShoppingCartItems.Id FROM ShoppingCartItems WHERE ShoppingCartItems.ProductID = @ProductID AND ShoppingCartItems.ShoppingCartId = @ShoppingCartId)
    --Om produkten existerar
        BEGIN
            UPDATE ShoppingCartItems
            SET Quantity = Quantity + 1
            WHERE ProductID = @ProductID AND ShoppingCartItems.ShoppingCartId = @ShoppingCartId
        END
    ELSE
--Om inte produkten existerar
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ShoppingCartItems(ShoppingCartId,ProductID, Quantity)
        VALUES(@ShoppingCartId, @ProductID, @Quantity)
    END
ELSE
--Om Kundvagnen inte existerar
--Insert ny kundvagn
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ShoppingCart(UserID, DateAdded)
        VALUES(@UserID, GETDATE())
        SET @ShoppingCartId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        INSERT INTO ShoppingCartItems(ShoppingCartId,ProductID, Quantity)
        VALUES(@ShoppingCartId, @ProductID, @Quantity)
    END
```

Comment: Yes, it's the missing `BEGIN`/`END` around the final group of statements, which means the `ELSE` guards just the `INSERT` into `ShoppingCart` and then the final two statements (involving `SCOPE_IDENTITY`) were running no matter which parts of the `IF`/`ELSE` blocks had previously executed. So it reset `ShoppingCartId` to null since there hadn't been any `IDENTITY` inserts in this scope and then tried a further insert into `ShopingCartItems`.